# ListView with a ListView header

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with adding a listview as a header in my listview (go go redundancy). The code is working, however only the first item shows up in the header. The body looks fine.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.default_list_view);
header = (ListView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.savings_overview_header_list, null, false);
HeaderAdapter hAdapter = new HeaderAdapter(getLayoutInflater());

hAdapter.addItem("1");
hAdapter.addItem("2");
hAdapter.addItem("3");

header.setAdapter(hAdapter);    

for (Policy p : saving.getPolicies()) {
    adapter.addItem(p);
}

listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**headerView:**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/default_list_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
android:dividerHeight="2px"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_background_selected" 
>
</ListView>
```

I have tried wrapping the ListView in a vertical LinearLayout but no cigar there either :(

**hAdapter**

```
private static class HeaderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    protected ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public HeaderAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    public void addItem(String s) {
        data.add(s);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final PolicyViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.savings_overview_header_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PolicyViewHolder();

            holder.header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_header);
                            holder.subHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_subheader);
                            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_img);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PolicyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String s = data.get(position);

        holder.header.setText(s);
                    holder.subHeader.setText(s);
        holder.img.setImageResId(R.drawable.test);

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private static class PolicyViewHolder {
        TextView header;
                    TextView subHeader;
                    ImageView img;
    }
}
```

**header_item**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/list_item_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_image"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_header"
            style="@style/header_list_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_subheader"
            style="@style/list_header_sub_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sub header" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have tried to wrap a linearlayout="vertical" around this one as well

Comment: you should show what HeadaAdapter has inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the parent view how to stack your elememnts. This is necessary for parents like a LinearLayout. If you're going to have such an adapter, you need to have a parent to contain these things, UNLESS its a single view.

**Update**

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.
>
> A custom adater would inflate the views piece by piece, this can be
>   dynamic of fixed.

Comment: I have allready a parent linearlayout with orientation="vertical"

Comment: post R.layout.savings_overview_header_item .

Comment: header item looks wrong. Why do you have a relative layout containing it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6943/discussion-between-joxtraex-and-flexo)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem relates to Android simply not knowing how to handle the two levels of "scrollability" this design implies. Think about it - If the user drags over the header, how is Android supposed to know whether they mean to scroll the outer list or the list within the header? I once recall Romain Guy making the same point about placing `ListView`s inside `ScrollView`s, it's slightly meaningless.

What's probably happening is that Android makes the header big enough to simply display a single header list item and it assumes any dragging gesture by the user should apply to the outer list.

Generally, I think what you've described sounds like a bad design choice and you need to take a step back.

What functionally do you want this UI to do?

If it's simply that you want to display two sets of content within a single list, then this is a problem you need to solve within the `ListAdapter` implementation you're using. e.g. Take a look [Jeff Sharkey's blog post on his `SeparatedListAdapter`](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/).

Answer (score 0):

Make a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and add both ListViews there. That should fix your hiccup. 
Cheers.